# Performance logging on Cloudflare Workers

Tags: sentry, cloudflare-workers

Is it possible to add Sentry performance monitoring to Cloudflare Workers? The current Toucan-js library works well for event logging, but doesn't seem to support `startTransaction`.

Using the official SDK has not worked for me - the const that receives `startTransaction` is undefined when I subsequently use it to `startChild`.

Official Sentry SDK:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/performance/instrumentation/custom-instrumentation/

Comment: Cloudflare Workers allow outbound HTTP traffic only, and only to DNS names. So behind the scenes, if the Sentry calls are trying to use an IP or make any non-HTTP calls, Workers won't allow it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not the author but I'm using https://github.com/robertcepa/toucan-js for my own CF projects. This Sentry client is explicitly created for Workers and supports `startTransaction`.

Here's a simple example:

```
import { Toucan } from 'toucan-js';
import '@sentry/tracing';


type Env = {
    SENTRY_DSN: string;
};

export default {
    async fetch(request, env, context): Promise<Response> {
        const sentry = new Toucan({
            dsn: env.SENTRY_DSN,
            tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
            context,
            request,
        });

        const transaction = sentry.startTransaction({ name: 'someRandomName' });
        try {
            handler();
            return new Response('Hello!');
        } catch (e) {
            sentry.captureException(e);

            return new Response('Something went wrong! Team has been notified.', {
                status: 500,
            });
        } finally {
            transaction.finish();
        }
    },
} as ExportedHandler<Env>;
```

To create a span, simply do `const span = transaction.startChild({ op: 'someFunction' })`. Just remember to call `span.finish()` at the end of it.

Comment: Thanks for the really useful answer, I was `sentry.startTransaction()` coming back `undefined` and this was because I'd missed the `import '@sentry/tracing';`